# Google maps geocoder is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary

Hi i am getting geocoder undefined error. 
What i trying is to show google map on page load.
Below is my code

```
    var geocoder;
  var map;
function initialize() {
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
var mapOptions = {
 zoom: 8,
center: latlng
}
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
var address = document.getElementById('shipAddress').value;
//alert(address);
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
} else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
});

 });
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Any help will be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.ready`(where you try to access `geocoder`) will fire before `window.onload`(where you create the `Geocoder`-instance).

Append the code for `document.ready` to `initialize`

Comment: Thanks Molle, map worked after using                                         $(document).ready(function() { initialize(); }); in place of   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure you have

```
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=3&amp;sensor=false"
 type="text/javascript"></script>
```

prior to running the javascript code.

That's what messed me up.

Comment: Upvote, although nowadays `sensor` is deprecated and you have to provide an API key